# PHP - Find array by name given as string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I've got some arrays like this
`$something = array('foo' => 'bar');`

Now how can I get the content of `$something`? I want to use this method to retrieve values from arrays but can't work out how to find an array with only it's name given as a string.

```
getArrayData($array,$key){
    // $array == 'something';
    // $key == 'foo';
    // this should return 'bar'
}
```

EDIT:

I abstracted this too much maybe, so here is the full code:

```
class Config {
public static $site = array(
    'ssl' => 'true',
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    // ...
);

public static $menu = array(
    'home' => '/home',
    '/hub' => '/hub',
    // ...
);

public static function get($from, $key){
    return self::$from[$key];
    }

public static function __callStatic($method, $key){
    return self::get($method,$key);
    }
}
```

In the end the configuration should be accessible from within the whole app by using `Config::site('charset')` to return `'utf-8'`

Comment: Can you show us an example of `how to find an array with only it's name given as a string.`?

Comment: `$$` - may help. check this out - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: I tried to use variable variables in `get()`, eg. `return self::$$from[$key]` but it didn't work as expected and returned null...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Variable-Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
<?php
$something = array('foo' => 'bar');
$key="foo";
$arrayName="something";

echo getArrayData($$arrayName,$key);   // Notice the use of $$

function getArrayData($array,$key){
  return isset($array[$key])? $array[$key] : NULL ;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/4auLpvlp)**

Comment: That's exactly as I would have expected it to work, but it won't. So I guess I made some mistake in the static context, as it only returns `Access to undeclared static property`..

Comment: Can we see your actual complete code that's related and not bits of it? If you could include your whole class and how you call the method that would help

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the array itself as parameter instead of the name. Then you can just return the value by the given key:

```
function getArrayData($array,$key){
    return $array[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$array == 'something'` doesn't mean much, you can easily check the array keys and return the value if the key exists:

```
function getArrayData($array,$key){
  if(isset($array[$key])) return $array[$key];
  else return "";
}
```